# How can I join two tables in this specific situation?

Tags: sql, optimization

Given Table A and Table B.
Table A contains instance_id and type, type only keeps value T or F
Table B contains user_id and entitlement, entitlement only keeps value 1,2,3

Requirement:
T type should keep all entitlement value 1,2,3
F type should keep only entitlement value 1,2

My solution:

```
select A.issue_id, A.type from A
join
(select B.user_id, entitlement from B where entitlement in (1,2,3)) tB
where A.type = 'T'
union all
select A.issue_id, A.type from A
join
(select B.user_id, entitlement from B where entitlement in (1,2)) tB
where A.type = 'F'
```

Is there a better way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

From an indexing point of view, the union may already be optimal.  But, I would do away with the subqueries and just write straight joins:

```sql
SELECT a.issue_id, a.type
FROM A a
INNER JOIN B b
WHERE a.type = 'T' AND b.entitlement IN (1, 2, 3)
UNION ALL
SELECT a.issue_id, a.type
FROM A a
INNER JOIN B b
WHERE a.type = 'F' AND b.entitlement IN (1, 2);
```

The following indices should help this query:

```sql
CREATE INDEX a_idx ON A (type, issue_id);
CREATE INDEX b_idx ON B (entitlement);
```

While the two halves of your union query *could* be combined into a single query, doing so would involve introducing `OR` conditions in the `WHERE` clause, which would probably mean that any index cannot be used.